# Добавление кнопок в таблицу и привязка к ним функций Py Qt 5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtablewidget

У меня есть таблица (`tableWidget`), в которую я добавляю данные следующим образом:

```
    list_to_add = [('operation_1', 'warning', '2021/5/3/22/51/31', '0000/03/00/00/00/00', 'comment1', 'algorithm to solve1', 1), ('operation_2', 'critical', '2021/4/24/11/41/19', '0000/01/00/00/00/00', 'comment2', 'algorithm to solve2', 2), ('operation_3', 'warning', '2021/4/3/22/57/42', '0000/02/00/00/00/00', 'comment3', 'algorithm to solve3', 3)]

    buttons = [QPushButton(self.tableWidget) for i in range(len(list_to_add))]

    for timer, button in zip(list_to_add, buttons):
        rowPos = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPos)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 0, QTableWidgetItem(timer[0]))

        datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(timer[2], '%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S')
        time_delta = (datetime_obj - datetime.now()).total_seconds()
        new_value = self.convert_sec_to_time(time_delta)

        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 1, QTableWidgetItem(new_value))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 2, QTableWidgetItem(timer[4]))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPos, 3, QTableWidgetItem(timer[5]))
        button.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton"
            "{"
             "background-color: white ;"
             "border-radius:5px;"
             "color: black;"
             "border: 2px solid rgb(247, 247, 247);"
             "border-color: green"
             "}"

             "QPushButton:hover"
             "{"
              "border: 2px solid rgb(247, 247, 247);"
              "border-color: orange;"
              "}"

              "QPushButton:pressed"
              "{"
              "background-color: rgb(88, 88, 88);"
              "}"
              )
        button.setText('Сбросить')
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.reset_timers(timer[6], rowPos))
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(rowPos, 4, button)
```

Я хочу, чтобы кнопка в каждой строке была связана с функцией `self.reset_timers(timer[6], rowPos)`, в которую передавался бы уникальный идентификатор `timer_id = timer[6]`, указывающий на то, какой именно таймер надо заменить.

При моем подходе все кнопки связываются с функцией `self.reset_timers(timer[6], rowPos)`, аргументы которой соответствуют **последней строке таблицы** (`timer_id =3` и `rowPos =2`).

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу исправить код, чтобы каждая кнопка была связана с функцией `self.reset_timers`, в которую передавался бы `id` и номер строки, соответствующей данной записи.

В голову приходит динамическое объявление переменных, но я слышал, что это не очень хороший вариант.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы получать быстрые и правильные ответы - предоставляйте, пожалуйста, минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Я не могу проверить то что вы опубликовали, но предложу попробовать заменить строку:

```
    button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.reset_timers(timer[6], rowPos))
```

на строку:

```
    button.clicked.connect(
        lambda ch, t=timer[6], r=rowPos:  self.reset_timers(t, r)
    )
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)
а почему это сработало, можете объяснить, пожалуйста?